# CFArrayGetValueAtIndex: How to determine if return value is a CFType or not

Tags: core-foundation

This is from the Apple Developers website:

const void * CFArrayGetValueAtIndex (
   CFArrayRef theArray,
   CFIndex idx
);

Return Value
The value at the idx index in theArray. If the return value is a Core Foundation Object, ownership follows “The Get Rule” in Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation.

Now, how does one test if the return value is a CFType or not?

EDIT:

Just found a function in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib called __isctype, which does exactly what i'm looking for. Does somebody know more about this function?

Comment: `__isctype()` has nothing to do with CFTypes. It's used to determine the "class" of a character (i.e. is it a digit, or a letter, etc.) It's also a private function.

Comment: How embarrassing for me. I'm working for too many hours... And of course there is no RTTI capability in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you should always know the family of objects which is provided to you.

If it's not a CF-compatible type (that includes `NSObject`s), then you ought to just know by explicit documentation. Either you constructed a very unusual CFArray, or the client would indicate this (e.g. by specifying the array contains pointers to some struct). It's a safe default assumption, and every call that does not return CF-compatible objects in their CFArray should make it loud and clear.

If in doubt, you could always `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` a returned object during development (that should crash if it is not a CF-Type).